# Дочерние представления Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Допустим есть представление MainView. В нем (в функции инициализации) создается дочернее представление допустим listView.
При переходе по роутеру на другой url, в роутере вызывается функция для закрытия текущего представление и создание на его место нового.

Вопрос, как мне закрыть дочерний View если он может быть динамичным или вообще не известным для логики

Comment: Переопределять метод `remove` в `MainView` пробовали?

Comment: Не подумал об этом. Спасибо!